# html5 video player playlist loop

Tags: javascript

I have an array of videos. How do I play them all on loop?

My code (below) plays all the videos one by one but the problem is that it stops after the last video. I want it to start over again from first video.

I will appreciate any help.

Here is the code:

```js
var videoList = [/*...*/];

var curVideo = 0;
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
videoPlayer.onended = function() {
    curVideo++;
    if (curVideo < videoList.length) {
        videoPlayer.src = videoList[curVideo];
    } else if (curVideo == videoList.length) {
        console.log("list is finished");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I figured it out. This is the code maybe someone can benefit from it.

```
var videoList = [..]
var curVideo = 0;
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
videoPlayer.onended = function(){
    curVideo++;  

    if(curVideo < videoList.length){            
        videoPlayer.src = videoList[curVideo];  
      //  return;      
    }  
    if (curVideo == videoList.length){
        curVideo=0;
       videoPlayer.src = videoList[curVideo];       
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just do ``curVideo %= videoList.length;`` then you don't need either if or the code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Just use modulo (%). E.g.:

```js
var videos = [/*...*/];
var videoIndex = 0;
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
videoPlayer.onended = function(){
    videoIndex = (videoIndex + 1) % videos.length;
    videoPlayer.src = videos[videoIndex];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your `if` statement to `while` and then when `curVideo` reaches the end, set `curVideo` back to 0. That should create an infinite loop.

You would of course need to change your `else if` to an `if` to check to see if it's at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried but it does not work. Browser crashed because of infinite loop. I don't know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: can you make please jsfiddle example.